# Ajuda Query Sum

Tags: query, laravel-5, querybuilder

Estou tentando recuperar uma coluna e realizar uma soma — utilizando o `SUM` — de acordo com a faixa de horário, porém sem exito. Podem me ajudar com esta questão?

Detalhe: Não estou usando exatamente uma tabela, mas realizo a chamada de uma função do *SQL*. A aplicação funciona bem com esta função.

**Função executada:**

[image: Função SQL]

Segue trecho do controller

```
public function abertura( Request $request, $carteira, $dia, $servico, $segmento )
{

    $servico  = $servico == 'NULL' ? null : $servico;
    $segmento = $segmento == 'NULL' ? null : $segmento;

    $data = Date::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $dia, tz() );

    $servicos = Receptivo::makeSegmento( $data->format( 'Ymd' ), $carteira )
        ->orderByRaw( 'REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(NOME_SERVICO,\'SANTANDER_IN_VAREJO_\',\'\'),\'IN_\',\'\'),\'SERVICE_\',\'\'),\'VAREJO_\',\'\')' )
        ->get();

    $segmentos = Receptivo::makeSegmentoServico( ucfirst( strtolower( $carteira ) ) )
        ->selectRaw( 'distinct segmento' )->get();

    $datas = collect( range( 0, 90 ) )->map( function ( $incremento ) {
        return now_tz()->copy()->subDays( $incremento );
    } );

    $receb = Receptivo::makeAbertura( $data->format( 'Ymd' ), $carteira, $servico, $segmento )
        ->orderBy( 'Faixa_Horario' )->get();

    //Soma
    $Query = Receptivo::where('Faixa_Horario', 'Faixa_Horario')->sum('Atendimento_Cliente_com_Negocio');
    return view( 'reports.hora-a-hora.receptivo.abertura.index',
        compact( 'carteira', 'receb', 'datas', 'data', 'servico', 'servicos', 'segmento', 'segmentos', 'Query' ) );
}
```

**Trecho da model:**

```
    public static function makeAbertura( $date, $carteira, $servico = null, $segmento = null )
{
    /** @var static $instance */
    $instance = new static;

    $servico = $servico == null ? 'NULL' : "'" . $servico . "'";

    $segmento = $segmento == null ? 'NULL' : "'" . $segmento . "'";

    $table = sprintf( 'FN_HORA_HORA_RECEPTIVO_SANTANDER_%s_ABERTURA(\'%s\', %s, %s)',
        $carteira,
        $date,
        $servico,
        $segmento
    );
    //dd($table);
    return $instance->setTable( $table );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar `sum` você tem que ter aplicado a função `get` antes

```
$Query = Receptivo::where('Faixa_Horario', 'Faixa_Horario')->get()->sum('Atendimento_Cliente_com_Negocio');
```

Não entendi porque no seu where está: `where('Faixa_Horario', 'Faixa_Horario')` no segundo parametro você deve passar o valor que deseja igualar em seu where, exemplo:

```
$Query = Receptivo::where('Faixa_Horario', 8)->get()->sum('Atendimento_Cliente_com_Negocio');
```

Comment: Marcelo obrigado pelo retorno. adiciono Faixa_Horario pq hora tem q ser igual a hora, correto? Outra duvida nesta model tenho varia foções, como faço para charmar somente a função makeAbertura?

Comment: 'hora tem q ser igual a hora' não entendi muito bem oque quis dizer com isso, a minha duvida foi por que 'Faixa_Horario' não refere-se a númerico valor número que é o tipo da coluna. Para chamar somente a função makeAbertura ela deve ser static model exatamente como você colocou e chamada assim, passando seus parametros: Receptivo::makeAbertura($date, $carteira);

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo Zapatta, funcionou, realizei da seguinte maneira.

```
 $receb = Receptivo::makeAbertura( $data->format( 'Ymd' ), $carteira, $servico, $segmento )
        ->whereIn('FAIXA_HORARIO', range(8, 20))
        ->groupBy('FAIXA_HORARIO')
        ->selectRaw('FAIXA_HORARIO, SUM(ATENDIMENTO_COM_NEGOCIO) AS SOMA')
        ->orderBy('FAIXA_HORARIO')
        ->get();
```